# creating `alglib::integer_1d_array` with `Eigen::Matrix`

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3, alglib

I keep getting the error `error: no matching function for call to 'alglib::integer_1d_array::setcontent(int, Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 1> >::Scalar*)'`.

For some reason `alglib::integer_1d_array` doesn't like to be instantiated in the same way as the `alglib::real_1d_array`.

For example, inside a function template with template argument `size_t num`, and parameter `Eigen::Matrix<double,num,num> A`, this works:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double,num,num,Eigen::RowMajor> twice_A_rm(A);
real_2d_array a;
a.setcontent(num, num, twice_A_rm.data());
```

However, it doesn't work as soon as I change to the integer array:

```
Eigen::Matrix<int,num+1,1> ctEig = Eigen::Matrix<int,num+1,1>::Constant(1.0); // positive for >=
integer_1d_array ct;
ct.setlength(num+1);
ct.setcontent(num+1, ctEig.data());
```

I can also replace `num+1` with `static_cast<int>(num+1)` in the last line, and it still doesn't work. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly browsing through the source of alglib, it seems like `integer_1d_array` has data of type `ptrdiff_t` by default, i.e., your code should work, if you replace `int` by `ptrdiff_t` in the line you declare/initialize `ctEig`:

```
Eigen::Matrix<ptrdiff_t,num+1,1> ctEig = Eigen::Matrix<ptrdiff_t,num+1,1>::Constant(1);
integer_1d_array ct;
ct.setlength(num+1); // <-- I assume this line is redundant
ct.setcontent(num+1, ctEig.data());
```